# Missing Console.log output on deployment of a solidity contract

Tags: solidity, console

I have the following script in my `deploy.js`:

```
const hre = require("hardhat");
const main = async () => {
  const transactionsFactory = await hre.ethers.deployContract("Transactions");

  await transactionsFactory.waitForDeployment();

  console.log("Transactions address: ", transactionsFactory.getAddress());
  console.log("Transactions address: ", transactionsFactory.address);
  console.log("Transactions address: ", transactionsFactory.target);
  console.log("Hello World!");
};

const runMain = async () => {
  try {
    await main();
    process.exit(0);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
```

Comment: When I run npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli I see Compiled 1 Solidity file successfully in the terminal, but no other messages which I expected from the console.log statement. Now I am not sure if the contract was deployed successfully or not. Why is console.log not showing in the terminal? I am using VS Code Solidity extention by Juan Blanco, "hardhat": "^2.15.0" and "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^3.0.0".